# Find the solution x in S5 to the following equation

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, symmetric-groups

I am asked to find the solution x in $S_5$to the following equation:

$(1 \ 3) \circ x \circ (2 \ 3 \ 5) = (3 \ 4)$

Here is my attempt,

$(1 \ 3)^{-1} \circ (1 \ 3) \circ x \circ (2 \ 3 \ 5) = (1 \ 3)^{-1} \circ (3 \ 4)$

$\Rightarrow \space$ $x \circ (2 \ 3 \ 5) = (3 \ 1) \circ (3 \ 4)$

$\Rightarrow \space$ $x \circ (2 \ 3 \ 5) \circ (2 \ 3 \ 5)^{-1} = (3 \ 1) \circ (3 \ 4) \circ (2 \ 3 \ 5)^{-1}$

$\Rightarrow \space$ $x = (3 \ 1) \circ (3 \ 4) \circ (5 \ 3 \ 2)$

$\Rightarrow \space$ $x = (3 \ 1) \circ (3 \ 4) \circ (5 \ 2) \circ (5 \ 3)   $

Is this correct so far?  Can I simplify further?  Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: Your approach seems correct. However you can certainly simplify.

Comment: It is probably better to write that product of 2-cycles as a product of disjoint cycles. Looks correct to me.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen ok, so I need to simplify the compositions on the right hand side of the equal sign in the last line?

Comment: I would recommend doing that. When I teach this stuff in freshman algebra I insist that the students do that. It is not necessary for all purposes, but it is good practice, and helps when comparing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivation is correct but you can go one step further and write:
$$x=(1\ 3\ 2\ 5\ 4),$$
assuming that $fg(i)=f(g(i))$. For example for $3$ we have $3\to5$ because of $(5\ 3)$ and then $5\to2$ because of $(5\ 2)$, so $3\to2$.

Comment: I will simplify and hopefully get the same answer you arrived at.